# Retrieving an IP address as a parameter inside a Django URL

Tags: python, regex, django, url, filter

My application is listing some game servers IP addresses.

I want to add a simple search engine, taking a regular expression in it. I would type `^200.` to list only the IP addresses beginning with `200.`

The form would redirect me to the results page by sending a GET request like that :

```
/servers/search/^200./page/1/range/30/
```

This is the line I'm using in `urls.py` :

```
url(r'^servers/search/(?P<search>[a-zA-Z0-9.]+)/page/(?P<page>\d+)/range/(?P<count>\d+)/$', gameservers.views.index)
```

But it doesn't work the way I expected. No results are shown. I've intentionally made a syntax error to see the local variables. Then I realized that the `search` variable's value is the following :

```
^200./page/1/range/30/
```

How can I fix this ? I've thought about moving the `search` parameter in the url's ending, but it might be very interesting to see if there is a way to limit the value with the next `/`.

Comment: Can you not add a number of search filters to the search. For example have a /servers/search/begins/200 or /servers/search/contains/300 or /servers/search/endswith/100

Comment: It would be too long, and I'd personally prefer using regular expressions instead of manual filters, thanks for the advice though !

Comment: Just remember that in some instances you will be adding special characters to the URL which you will need to encode. Also be aware of the slash character as that could alter the url if your not using it in the query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex doesn't match at all: you are not accepting the `^` character. But even if it was, there's no way that the full URL could all be captured in the `search` variable, because then the rest of the URL wouldn't match.

However, I wouldn't try to fix this. Trying to capture complicated patterns in the URL itself is usually a mistake. For a search value, it's perfectly acceptable to move that to a GET query parameter, so that your URL would look something like this:

```
/servers/search/?search=^200.&page=1&range=30
```

or, if you like, you could still capture the `page` and `range` values in the URL, but leave the `search` value as a query param.

Comment: Thanks, I agree this is one of the best solutions to avoid any confusion with the URL filtering feature, I've completely forgot it.